# How to use a dictionary to translate/replace elements of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a numpy array, which has hundreds of elements which are capital letters, in no particular order

```
import numpy as np
abc_array = np.array(['B', 'D', 'A', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'Z', 'J', ...])
```

Each element in this `numpy.ndarray` is a `numpy.string_`.

I also have a "translation dictionary", with key/value pairs such that the capital letter corresponds to a city

```
transdict = {'A': 'Adelaide', 'B': 'Bombay', 'C': 'Cologne',...}
```

There are only 26 pairs in the dictionary `transdict`, but there are hundreds of letters in the numpy array I must translate.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I have considered using `numpy.core.defchararray.replace(a, old, new, count=None)[source]` but this returns a `ValueError`, as the numpy array is a different size that the dictionary keys/values.

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'translate'`

Comment: Did you try out any code that works, be it *inefficient*? What's the expected output for the sample data?

Comment: @Divakar Actually, my best guess was to use `numpy.core.defchararray.replace()`, but that doesn't work. So yes, I don't know what to do.

Comment: For `old`, you need to use `transdict.keys()`, for `new` you need to use `transdict.values()`, Then `.replace(abc_array, old, new)` should work

Comment: @ChadS. I thought so too, but it doesn't. 
`abc_array` is a numpy array shaped (700,1), `old` and `new` are numpy arrays both shaped (26,1)

Comment: @ChadS. I get a broadcasting error: `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Comment: is there really a reason to have it as a numpy array instead of just a list? Why not yo try: `output = [transdict[letter] for letter in abc_array]
print (output) `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Will this do?  Sometimes, plain Python is a good, direct way to handle such things.  The below builds a list of translations (easily converted back to a numpy array) and the joined output.

```
import numpy as np
abc_array = np.array(['B', 'D', 'A', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'Z', 'J'])

transdict = {'A': 'Adelaide',
             'B': 'Bombay',
             'C': 'Cologne',
             'D': 'Dresden',
             'E': 'Erlangen',
             'F': 'Formosa',
             'G': 'Gdansk',
             'H': 'Hague',
             'I': 'Inchon',
             'J': 'Jakarta',
             'Z': 'Zambia'
}

phoenetic = [transdict[letter] for letter in abc_array]
print ' '.join(phoenetic)
```

The output from this is:

```
Bombay Dresden Adelaide Formosa Hague Inchon Zambia Jakarta
```

Comment: I think you're right; a Python for loop is the way to go.

Comment: Fine ... but you might wait around for other ideas, especially the pure numpy ones.  Don't forget to "accept" your favourite once you have a good solution.

Comment: Solution based on @Prune answer for those who have elements that shouldn't be replaced, so "transdict" contains only the elements that should be replaced:

```phoenetic = [(transdict[letter] if letter in transdict else letter) for letter in abc_array]```

Answer (score 14):

With *brute-force* [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
idx = np.nonzero(transdict.keys() == abc_array[:,None])[1]
out = np.asarray(transdict.values())[idx]
```

With [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) based searching and indexing -

```
sort_idx = np.argsort(transdict.keys())
idx = np.searchsorted(transdict.keys(),abc_array,sorter = sort_idx)
out = np.asarray(transdict.values())[sort_idx][idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [1]: abc_array = np.array(['B', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C'])
   ...: transdict = {'A': 'Adelaide', 'B': 'Bombay', 'C': 'Cologne', 'D': 'Delhi'}
   ...: 

In [2]: idx = np.nonzero(transdict.keys() == abc_array[:,None])[1]
   ...: out = np.asarray(transdict.values())[idx]
   ...: 

In [3]: out
Out[3]: 
array(['Bombay', 'Delhi', 'Adelaide', 'Bombay', 'Delhi', 'Adelaide',
       'Cologne'], 
      dtype='|S8')

In [4]: sort_idx = np.argsort(transdict.keys())
   ...: idx = np.searchsorted(transdict.keys(),abc_array,sorter = sort_idx)
   ...: out = np.asarray(transdict.values())[sort_idx][idx]
   ...: 

In [5]: out
Out[5]: 
array(['Bombay', 'Delhi', 'Adelaide', 'Bombay', 'Delhi', 'Adelaide',
       'Cologne'], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

Comment: Didn't you just answer another dicitonary question with searchsorted? :)

Comment: @hpaulj Isn't that fun!? ;) *NumPythonic* everything :)

Comment: Something which caught me be surprise. The first method will fail on large data structures with unhelpful error messages. As far as I can tell `==` starts returning `True`/`False` above some limit rather than broadcasting.

Comment: For Python 3 both `keys()` and `values()` have to be wrapped in `list` statements.

Comment: Reading your answers always blows my mind haha, cool to have you doing all this!