# replace numpy elements with non-scalar dictionary values

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
column = np.array([5505, 5505, 5505, 34565, 34565, 65539, 65539])
column = pd.Series(column)
myDict = column.groupby(by = column ).groups
```

I am creating a `dictionary` from a `pandas df` using `df.group(by=..)` which has the form:

```
>>> myDict
{5505: Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64'), 65539: Int64Index([5, 6], dtype='int64'), 34565: Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64')}
```

I have a `numpy array`, e.g.

```
myArray = np.array([34565, 34565, 5505,65539])
```

and I want to replace each of the array's elements with the dictionary's values. 
I have tried several solutions that I have found (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403973/fast-replacement-of-values-in-a-numpy-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529593/how-to-use-a-dictionary-to-translate-replace-elements-of-an-array)) but these examples have dictionaries with single dictionary `values`, and I am always getting the error of `setting an array element with a sequence`. How can I get over this problem?

My intended output is

```
np.array([3, 4, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal complete/reproducible sample dictionary?

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I am not sure how to create a small initial pandas column from which to generate the dictionary (because groupby only works on a pandas object, not an array)

Comment: @Divakar  I have reworked this into a reproducible example now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach based on [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
# Extract dict info
k = list(myDict.keys())
v = list(myDict.values())

# Use argsort of k to find search sorted indices from myArray in keys
# Index into the values of dict based on those indices for output
sidx = np.argsort(k)
idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(k,myArray,sorter=sidx)]
out_arr = np.concatenate([v[i] for i in idx])
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [369]: myDict
Out[369]: 
{5505: Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64'),
 34565: Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64'),
 65539: Int64Index([5, 6], dtype='int64')}

In [370]: myArray
Out[370]: array([34565, 34565,  5505, 65539])

In [371]: out_arr
Out[371]: array([3, 4, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it needs to be `k = list(myDict.keys())` or otherwise I am getting the error `'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'searchsorted'`. Same for `v` of course ..

Comment: @Tony I am on Python 2.7. That should be a Python 3.x requirement. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: So, @Divakar, the only way to achieve this is with the list comprehension right? There's no way to avoid the loop there from what I gather ?

Comment: On a separate note, do you perhaps have a good resource to suggest about numpy, vectorised operations and all these indexing, slicing and sorting possibilities that you are expert on? I really cannot tune my mind away from loops.

Comment: @Tony Nope, can't vectorize that loop. On the vectorization resources, well all I have learnt is through practicing on SO, following the [`ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) and generally being persuasive about avoiding loops.